# opentok subscriber connection and disconnection keeps firing in loop

Tags: cordova, opentok, crosswalk

I am using opentok version 2.10.2 javascript sdk. I am using this SDK in my Cordova Android app which is running crosswalk as the webview.

The issue arises when network switches from wifi to 4G or vice versa while on a video chat. The opentok's auto reconnection logic kicks in and sessionReconnected fires. Till this point all fine. But soon, the subscriber connected and disconnected starts firing in a continuous loop. What could be the possible reason behind this? The call state is such that the remote video feed is not seen in both the end points but the audio remains.

Any feedback on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Abhik, this kind of problem will probably require a session ID to debug. Since that's private info, I'd recommend emailing Tokbox support directly.